# Creating a custom calendar in joda time

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I need to be able to create custom calendars that can omit certain holidays which I specify from the date set. I might for instance, need to create a map keyed on the date, but only want to loop through the dates which omit certain holidays. An example would be that I want to see how much electricity in kWH german gov't buildings used on a given day, but omit the holidays.  I thought about using `joda-time` for this, considering I might have a map keyed like `<DateTime, Double>`, but I am not sure if that would work.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the word Calendar in the "business Calendar" sense, and not in a sense that `java.util.Calendar` or a Joda `Chronology` would understand.  Basically, your "Calendar" is the application of rules which sub-select a set of Joda `Intervals` from a Joda `Chronology`.

I believe that you will find that instead of trying to build another business calendar system on top of Joda, you might be better off using [ObjectLabKit](http://objectlabkit.sourceforge.net/), which is a business library that has support for business calendars, including holiday rules etc.

Hopefully the rules will support all of the scenarios in your *locale*.  Sometimes different locations don't share enough of the same assumptions about time to actually use a semi-generic library.

Answer (score 0):

Check is day holiday manualy

```
private static final List<LocalDate> HOLIDAYS = Arrays.asList(new LocalDate[]{
   new LocalDate(2000, DateTimeConstants.JANUARY, 1),
   new LocalDate(2000, DateTimeConstants.JANUARY, 7),
   new LocalDate(2000, DateTimeConstants.JANUARY, 14),
   new LocalDate(2000, DateTimeConstants.JANUARY, 28),
   /* ... */
   new LocalDate(2000, DateTimeConstants.DECEMBER, 25),
});

public static boolean isHoliday(LocalDate checkedDate)
{
    for (final LocalDate date : HOLIDAYS)
    {
        if(date.getMonthOfYear() == checkedDate.getMonthOfYear()
                && date.getDayOfMonth() == checkedDate.getDayOfMonth())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would avoid keeping the holidays in code... it's even worse than [this daily WTF...](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Time_for_a_tblHoliday.aspx)...

Answer (score 0):

as @EdwinBuck said, your terminologies are confusing and making people difficult to understand your problem.

I have no idea why you want a Map ? What's the value for?

If you are looking for some lookup to know whether certain day is a holiday, using a Set is probably more meaningful.  (I have not used Joda date time before, just writing something sensible here)

e.g.

```
Set<DateTime> holidays = new HashSet<DateTime>();
holidays.add(....);
// add all holidays to the set

// if you need to check if certain day is holiday so you can skip it:
if (!holidays.contains(someDay)) {
  // it is not a holiday
  // do anything you need
}
```